# What is meaning of output of WEXITSTATUS on linux. Return status from waitpid for child process

Tags: wexitstatus

What is the meaning of returning WEXITSTATUS on Linux if WEXITSTATUS is returning child process status as 170 and if WIFEXITED returns true?